# Dependency and Association in terms of code

Tags: java

I have a question about dependency and association. My understanding on the terms dependency is that it is like a loose kind of relation, I think of the two class being unrelated but i need to use the other class to complete a task. While association is more like a logical connection between two classes. May I check if my understanding is correct? Is dependency a relation that only affects a part of my code while association is creating a instance inside the other class? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding on the terms dependency is that it is like a loose kind of relation, I think of the two class being unrelated but i need to use the other class to complete a task. While association is more like a logical connection between two classes

Yes. And there is one important feature: association is always a dependency too

An example of association (field in class):

```
class A { ... }
class B {
    private A a;
    public B(A a) { ... }
    ...
}
```

And this is example of a dependency (usage in some method):

```
class A { public void doA() { ... } }
class B {
    public void doA(A a) { a.doA(); ... }
    ...
}
```

**PS**: it is just an example. Usage as return type in some method also implies a dependency (real world pattern example - `AbstractFactory`)

Comment: in terms of design what factor should I use to decide one relations over the other?

Comment: association allows you to keep `A` class instance in a `B` instance state. There are many pros and cons for each pattern. For example association  is a common way to make methods in `B` more concise (do not need to pass some object instance to every method, we can use `this.a`). And dependency is a good for design patterns like factories... It is just an examples, both of these relations are widely used

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand why association is always a dependency. Is it because it have all of A method can be used since the instance is passed in?

Comment: because in association you must allways pass an instance through constructor or setter - and this pass is a dependency :)